# How do I use vertices?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vertices

***I'm trying to create a colored line, using the distance between two vertices on a cube as the start and end of a line.***

---

Consider the following code:

```cs-sharp
Vector3[] verticesArray = transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.vertices;
```

I was told the `verticesArray` is ordered in a clockwise direction, I was also told `verticesArray` was populated with locally positioned vertex positions.

---

My question is how are the vertices ordered, is it top then bottom, left to right? Are they[Vertices] locally positioned or world positioned? How do they relate to the `GameObject`, for example do they have a reference point like the center of the object, is that what makes them locally positioned?

---

I tried adding a random vertex value to the position of the object I'm trying to find the vertex of in `transform.TransformPoint()` to see if the vertex was locally position and if there was some order in the `verticesArray` array, sadly the location was far off from the target not answering my questions.

Answer (score 1):

> I was told the `verticesArray` is ordered in a clockwise direction
>
> My question is how are the vertices ordered, is it top then bottom, left to right?

**Nope!** The [`Mesh.vertices`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-vertices.html) are **not** necessarily ordered **at all**! That totally would depend on how that mesh was created. Note that "top to bottom" or "left to right" has no real meaning in 3D anyway.

What you can do though is rather go through the [`Mesh.triangles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-triangles.html).

That is an array of `int`. They are "ordered" in the way that a set of **3** consequent elements refers to one triangle and the order decides into which direction the triangle faces (clockwise / counter-clockwise). The `int` values in `triangles` refer to the indices of according 3 vertices within the `vertices` array. Multiple triangles can even share common vertices by simply referring to the same index in `vertices`.

This probably also makes more sense since there is no line/edge between each and every vertex but you seem to be more interested in the triangles anyway.

> Are they[Vertices] locally positioned or world positioned? And How they relate to the `GameObject`, for example do they have a reference point like the center of the object, is that what makes them locally positioned?

These are the vertices in the original `Mesh`. They are not scaled, rotated or translated. So in other words, yes, they are in **local space**. The positions in the `Mesh` are all relative to the `GameObject`'s pivot point.

Using [`Transform.TransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html) - as you did - should result in the correct according world-space positions.

```c#
var mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;

// Iterate over the triangles in sets of 3
for(var i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i += 3)
{
    // Get the 3 consequent int values
    var aIndex = triangles[i];
    var bIndex = triangles[i + 1];
    var cIndex = triangles[i + 2];

    // Get the 3 according vertices
    var a = vertices[aIndex];
    var b = vertices[bIndex];
    var c = vertices[cIndex];

    // Convert them into world space
    // up to you if you want to do this before or after getting the distances
    a = transform.TransformPoint(a);
    b = transform.TransformPoint(b);
    c = transform.TransformPoint(c);

    // Get the 3 distances between those vertices
    var distAB = Vector3.Distance(a, b);
    var distAC = Vector3.Distance(a, c);
    var distBC = Vector3.Distance(b, c);

    // Now according to the distances draw your lines between "a", "b" and "c" e.g.
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.TransformPoint(a), transform.TransformPoint(b) /*, someColorDependingOnDistAB*/);
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.TransformPoint(a), transform.TransformPoint(c) /*, someColorDependingOnDistAC*/);
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.TransformPoint(b), transform.TransformPoint(c) /*, someColorDependingOnDistBC*/);
}
```